# how to loop through this json such that only the last type and source are taken and looped so that they are taken seperately in a function in jquery

Tags: json

```
[
    {
        "val":"al",
        "co1": "1",
        "co2": "2",
        "co3": "3",
        "stype1":"image",
        "ssource1":"assets/json images/636565581564595548-Kennedy.jpg",
        "stype2":"video",
        "ssource2":"mg7ya4E8SO0"
    },
    {
        "val":"al",
        "co1": "4",
        "co2": "5",
        "co3": "6",
        "stype1":"image",
        "ssource1":"assets/json images/636565581564595548-Kennedy.jpg",
        "sourcetype2":"video",
        "sourcesource2":"mg7ya4E8SO0"}

]
```

how to loop through this json such that only the last type and source are taken and looped so that they are taken seperately in a function in jquery.so that i can take only the last two i.e stype and source and loop them

Comment: Which programming language? What is your expected output? Please [edit] your question and add some details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which fields you mean, but what about something like this ?

In case there are multiple same keys, they are replaced in res Object, but taking anything containing key or source, so more results than you may want.

JNode IIFE is my own (source [here](https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Node_Iterator_IIFE.js) on Github).

```js
function demo(json) {
    var o = JNode(json);
    var res = {};
    do {
        if (o.hasOwnKey &&
          (o.key.indexOf('type') > -1
        || o.key.indexOf('source') > -1)) {
            res[o.key] = o.obj;
        }
    } while (o = o.DepthFirst())
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 1));
}
var data = [{"val":"al","co1": "1","co2": "2","co3": "3","stype1":"image","ssource1":"assets/json images/636565581564595548-Kennedy.jpg","stype2":"video","ssource2":"mg7ya4E8SO0"},{"val":"al","co1": "4","co2": "5","co3": "6","stype1":"image","ssource1":"assets/json images/636565581564595548-Kennedy.jpg","sourcetype2":"video","sourcesource2":"mg7ya4E8SO0"}];

// demo(data); called @ bottom under JNode definition

var JNode = (function (jsNode) {

    function JNode(json, parent, pred, key, obj, fill) {
        var node, pred = null;
        if (parent === undefined) {
            parent = null;
        } else if (fill) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.pred = pred;
            this.node = null;
            this.next = null;
            this.key = key;
            this.obj = obj;
            return this;
        }
        var current;
        var parse = (json instanceof Array);
        for (var child in json) {
            if (parse) child = parseInt(child);
            var sub = json[child];
            node = new JNode(null, parent, pred, child, sub, true);
            if (pred) {
                pred.next = node;
                node.pred = pred;
            }
            if (!current) current = node;
            pred = node;
        }
        return current;
    }

    JNode.prototype = {
        get hasNode() {
            if (this.node) return this.node;
            return (this.obj instanceof Object);
        },
        get hasOwnKey() { return this.key && (typeof this.key != "number"); },
        get level() {
            var level = 1, i = this;
            while(i = i.parent) level++;
            return level;
        },
        GoDown: function() {
            if (!this.node && this.obj instanceof Object) {
                this.node = new JNode(this.obj, this);
            }
            return this.node;
        },
        Stringify: function() { // Raw test stringify - #s are taken same as strings
            var res;
            if (typeof this.key == "number") {
                res = '[';
                var i = this;
                do {
                    if (i.node) res += i.node.Stringify();
                    else res += "undefined";
                    i = i.next;
                    if (i) res += ','
                } while(i);
                res += ']';
            } else {
                res = '{' + '"' + this.key + '":';
                res += (this.node?this.node.Stringify():this.hasNode?"undefined":'"'+this.obj+'"');
                var i = this;
                while (i = i.next) {
                    res += ',' + '"' + i.key + '":';
                    if (i.node) res += i.node.Stringify();
                    else {
                        if (i.obj instanceof Object) res += "undefined";
                        else res += '"' + i.obj + '"';
                    }
                };
                res += '}';
            }
            return res;
        },
        DepthFirst: function () {
            if (this == null) return 0; // exit sign
            if (this.node != null || this.obj instanceof Object) {
                return this.GoDown(); // moved down
            } else if (this.next != null) {
                return this.next;// moved right
            } else {
                var i = this;
                while (i != null) {
                    if (i.next != null) {
                        return i.next; // returned up & moved next
                    }
                    i = i.parent;
                }
            }
            return 0; // exit sign
        }
    }

    return JNode;
})();

demo(data);
```